# What does rt stands for in MIPS instruction format?

Tags: mips, abbreviation

Take MIPS instruction format described [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/format.html), there are some abbreviations eg rd,rs and rt. What does rt stands for? I know rt is the second source register in R-type instruction, and is the destination register in I-type instruction. It is easy to guess rd stands for register destination; rs stands for register source. What about rt?  I guess it might be "register temporary"? Is there an authoritative source about this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`t` is just the next letter after `s`, so `rs` is the *first* source register, `rt` is the *second* source register. (If there could be a third source register it would most likely be `ru`.)

Comment: what about I-Type commands, which only have RS and RT, and the result is written into RT?
https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/format.html

Comment: @yoav85: "I" in this context is just short-hand for "immediate". There are two registers and an immediate value.

Comment: I remember it as **r**egister **t**ransition, since it is sometimes a source and sometimes a destination

Answer (score 3):

rt stands for "register target". Just like been said above, in I-Type commands, the result is written into rt

Answer (score -1):

"register temporary", I think so.